# Having trouble looping this switch case statement

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

How can I loop this switch statement?

I want to change 3 button colors when another button is clicked. I need to infinite loop it after case 4 to case 1.
I am open to any other solutions.

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    i++;

    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            orange.BackColor = Color.Black;
            green.BackColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        case 2:
            red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            oragne.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            green.BackColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        case 3:
            red.BackColor = Color.Black;
            orange.BackColor = Color.Black;
            green.BackColor = Color.Green;
            break;
        case 4:
            red.BackColor = Color.Black;
            orange.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            green.BackColor = Color.Black;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: setting i = 0 when case 4 ?

Comment: Uh... use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Integer remainder, will make it for you. The sign of the non-zero remainder is the same as that of the left-hand operand

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    switch (i++ % 4)
    {
        case 0:
            red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            orange.BackColor = Color.Black;
            green.BackColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        case 1:
            red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            oragne.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            green.BackColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        case 2:
            red.BackColor = Color.Black;
            orange.BackColor = Color.Black;
            green.BackColor = Color.Green;
            break;
        case 3:
            red.BackColor = Color.Black;
            orange.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            green.BackColor = Color.Black;
            break;
    }
}
```

More reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators

Comment: This will be fine as long as you don't loop 2,147,483,648 times ...

Comment: @jasonmchoe in theory yes, but it requires 68 years with constant clicking, 1 pr second.